# How to split train and test data sets based on unique values?

Tags: r, machine-learning

I have a huge dataset, where the unique identifier is MAC address. The format of MAC is 00-00-0C-12-43-02. I also have date as a attribute. Currently I am 
splitting the datatset based on the date column. The code i am using is below, which is working.

```
set.seed(100)    
Date <- data.frame(unique(Clean_Data[,5]))    
dat_len <- length(unique(Clean_Data[,5]))    
Date_Split <- as.integer(dat_len*.70)    
train_ind <- Clean_Data[,5] <= Date[Date_Split+1,]    
test_ind <- !train_ind    
training<- Clean_Data[train_ind,]     
testing <- Clean_Data[test_ind,]
```

Clean_Data is my dataset, 5th column is the date column.

Now my requirement is to split the dataset by MAC address. but it is not working. 
Since it is a factor value i couldnt compare factor values with date values as above. Is there a different way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

at the creation of your data.frame use

```
data.frame(data, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

or to change factors into string (not tested)

```
Clean_Data[columnNumberOfMAC]=as.character(Clean_Data[columnNumberOfMAC])
```

however both solutions will require more RAM...
if that is an issue you can use the `as.character()` casting while comparing only, instead of changing the data.frame

Answer (score 0):

Obviously I can't test this since you didn't post the data, but you could try `sample_frac` from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

Clean_Data %>%
  group_by(date.column, MAC.column) %>%
  sample_frac(., 0.7)
```

Replace `date.column` with the name of your date column and `MAC.column` with your MAC address column.